# Install cython on python 3.x

Tags: python, aptitude

I need to install cython for python3.x .I have an ubuntu installation with python 2.6, 2.7 and 3.2 on it. Trying to `apt-get` the cython package installs `pymodules` only in 2.x versions. Is there a way to target a specific version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Cython Wiki](http://wiki.cython.org/Installing), you have a few choices for installing. One of them is:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev build-essential
```

You can also download the latest version from [Cython](http://cython.org/). Just untar/unzip the package, and then run (as superuser/sudo/root):

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: The apt-get command did not install cython. I suppose that I should browse the cython source code for available options. As for the second, the python alias is bound to python2.7, should I try something like python3.2 setup.py install ?

Comment: @kaiseroskilo you could try that, I don't believe it matters, it seems

Answer (score 9):

python 2 and 3 are in separate packages so for python 2

```
sudo apt-get install  cython
```

and for python3

```
sudo apt-get install  cython3
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:

```
$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get upgrade

$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip

$ pip3 install --no-cache-dir Cython
```

## Find the version of Cython and check whether Cython is installed for Python3

```
$ python3 -c "import Cython; print(Cython.__version__)"
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `print(Cython.__version__)`?

Comment: try:    #there could be many ways but the easiest was the above one.
            import Cython
            cython_ver = Cython.__version__
        except:
            cython_ver = 'None'
        print("Cython Version:     %s" % cython_ver)